# PHP - how to load HTML files?

Tags: php, html

At the moment I have a file like this

```
<?php
if(some condition)
{
    //Dont allow access
}
else
{
    echo "<html>My HTML Code</html>";
}
?>
```

But I wanted to do something like this to keep my php file short and clean.

```
<?php
if(some condition)
{
    //Dont allow access
}
else
{
    //print the code from ..html/myFile.html
}
?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` ?

Comment: if it's plain HTML use [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you may have a look at [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), seems a good idea for your needs! Example:

```
// Create a DOM object from a string
$html = str_get_html('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');

// Create a DOM object from a URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Create a DOM object from a HTML file
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');
```

Answer (score 19):

save your html content as seperate template and simply include it

```
<?php
if(some condition)
{
    //Dont allow access
}
else
{
    include ("your_file.html");
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
if(some condition)
{
    //Dont allow access
}
else
{
    readfile("your_file.html");
}
?>
```

`readfile` is faster and less memory intensive than `file_get_contents`

Comment: lol..how on earth did I forget about the plain old `include()`...

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But now I just have another question. do you know if I can edit a certain div within this php file. Like a div with a certain id?

Comment: @AnkurSharma: [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php) - Improve your search skills and you will get a lot of good answers to all your programming questions in no time.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
if(some condition)
{
    //Dont allow access
}
else
{
    echo file_get_contents("your_file.html");
}
```

OR

```
if(some condition)
{
    //Dont allow access
}
else
{
    require_once("your_file.html");
}
```

Comment: Which technique is better?

Comment: I will prefer 2nd one.

Answer (score 3):

Extending nauphal's answer for a more robust solution..

```
<?php
if(some condition)
{
    //Dont allow access
}
else
{
    if(file_exists("your_file.html"))
    {
       include "your_file.html";
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'Opps! File not found. Please check the path again';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use functions like

```
include()
include_once()
require()
require_once()
file_get_contents()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SysDragon why this is not an answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if(some condition)
{
    //Dont allow access
}
else
{
    echo file_get_contents("your_file.html");
}
?>
```

This should do the trick

Or, as [nauphal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932319/nauphal)'s answer say, simply use `include()`

Don't forget that, if file doesn't exists, you could have some trouble (so, maybe, check before include or getting content)

Comment: `file_get_contents()` returns a value, I don't see any echo or assignment above =oP

Comment: @crypticツ: yes, you're right. Thought wrote it .... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to include your HTML file or have I misunderstood the question.

```
<?php
if(some condition)
{
    //Dont allow access
}
else
{
    include ("..html/myFile.html");
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Way 1:

```
ob_start();
include "yourfile.html";
$return = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

echo $return;
```

Way 2:
Use templaters, like *CTPP*, *Smarty*, etc...
Templaters are useful to transfer some logic from php to template, for example, in CTPP:

```
$Templater -> params('ok' => true);
$Template -> output('template.html');
```

in template html:

```
<TMPL_if (ok) >
ok is true
<TMPL_else>
ok not true
</TMPL_if>
```

The same ideas are in other templaters.
Templaters are better, cause it helps you to standartize your templates and send all primitive logic to them.